# rails - how to let the client choose location for download a file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, csv

I create an option to export a csv file via my rails code, it's look like this :
 def to_csv
    company = current_company
    @opportunities = company.opportunities.company_visible.not_rejected

```
CSV.open("/Users/yarden/Downloads/file6.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << @opportunities.attribute_names
  @opportunities.all.each do |opportunity|
    csv << opportunity.attributes.values
  end
end
```

end

and, I added a btn in the client side (using Angular and js) for this function. 
However, my question is - how can I let the client choose where to locate the file in his pc, when he tried to download the csv file ? 
right now for my testing I wrote a a specific root in my pc for it.

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will only save the file locally on the server. If you want to let a user download the file, I'd advise you to save this CSV to a [tempfile](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), then sending it to the user by using the following method in the controller

```
// Controller action is called 'download_file'
def download_file
    // Generate file
    send_file my_generated_csv
end
```

The user then can download the file by clicking a link routing him to this action. You can find more information on the `send_file` method in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)